# Electric Ford Focus - all lights flashing when trying to start it

Tags: ford, focus, electric-vehicle

I have an Electric Ford Focus and this morning I tried to start it and all of the lights inside and outside just started flashing and going crazy. The app I have on my phone says that the charge finished this morning. I plugged it back in and the car isn't reading that the charger is plugged into it. The car won't turn on or do anything except flash all of the lights.